# How to instantiate a Class<? extends Tag> object?

Tags: java, class, generics

I'm using a new API and I'm having trouble instanciating a Class object, the API defines an abstract class Tag and its children named like IntTag, DoubleTag, StringTag, ListTag... etc. I'm fighting with the last one at the moment because
The constructor is as follows:

```
public ListTag(final String name, final Class<? extends Tag> type, final List<Tag> value);
```

So basically I have no problem with the first field and the last field, it's like a json object, this one is a list so you enter the name and what's inside, but I don't understand the middle one, I don't understand how I can instantiate this kind of object and what should I put inside it.

Any suggestions? I just learnt about ? extends Tag instead of Tag so that's not my problem, and also no need to explain me genericity (I hope?)

Thanks in advance!

--

Also if you want I downloaded the API from [here](https://github.com/Morlok8k/JNBT).

Comment: You can't.  `Class<? extends Tag>` is an abstract type.  Just use `Class<Tag>` instead, by passing `Tag.class`.

Comment: How about `new ListTag("some Name", IntTag.class, myList)`.

Comment: You dont need to instantiate an object of that type, you give it any object which is of type Tag or any subtype of Tag.

Comment: Thanks you for this quick answer, that's what I thought but I also tried to write Class<? extends Tag> t = new Class<Tag>(); but Eclipse tells me to "Add arguments to match 'Class<Tag>(ClassLoader, Class<?>)' and I don't understand this step.

Comment: Don't try to instantiate an object of type `Class` please. Just use `Classname.class` for that. In your case simply `Tag.class`.

Comment: Try passing `Tag.class` from wherever you are calling.

Comment: It works using IntTag.class but what if I want to insert different subtype of Tag, I'm asking because it won't let me use Tag.class.

Comment: Then use... `DoubleTag.class` or whatever else there is. In all honesty, if you did not understand it at this point you should go back to a tutorial on inheritance, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd pass in a class extending `Tag`, like `IntTag.class`, `DoubleTag.class`, etc.

The [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) type has no public constructor, so you can't instantiate one using the typical `new` syntax. You have to rely on the compiler to resolve [class literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) like `IntTag.class` or obtain instances via functions like [`Object.getClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--).